# Creating a dataset by web crawling

Tags: dataset, web-crawler, nutch

I want to build a dataset consisting about 2000-3000 web pages, starting with several seed URLs. I tried it using the Nutch crawler but I was unable to get it done (unable to convert the 'segments' data fetched into html pages) .

Any suggestions of a different crawler that you have used or any other tool? What if web pages contain absolute URLs which will make offline use of the dataset impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can NOT directly convert the nutch crawled segments to html files directly.

I suggest you these options:

1. You can try modifying the source code to do that. (study the `org.apache.nutch.segment.SegmentReader` class. You can then dig into it to modify the working as per your use case).
2. EASY SOLUTION if you dont want to invest time to study code: Use nutch to crawl all required pages. Then get the actual urls crawled by using the "`bin/nutch readdb`" command (use dump option). Then write a script to wget the urls and save it in html form. Done !!

Comment: I found this tool HTTrack which allows you to do it (but anyway I got away with the idea of creating a dataset and settled for a online crawl). thanks for your answer.